# Can't launch Android Studio

Tags: 12.04, android, ide

I have a fresh installation of Android Studio. Keep getting this:

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
 Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

How to make it work?

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Javac version:

```
javac 1.7.0_25
```

/etc/profile

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_25
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` give you in a terminal? And did you try to log out and log back in after changing the environment?

Comment: @gertvdijk You are totally right. I didn't log out :/ Sorry for making a fuss... Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try to log out and log back in.

After changing the environment settings, you'll have to *apply* them to your currently running session. If you're in a GUI session (Unity, KDE, Gnome or whatever), this is initiated by your display manager (LightDM, KDM for example) and you'll have to restart your system from there by logging out and back in.

Alternatively, you can change your current user environment in `~/.profile` and reload the environment *for that terminal* by running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

which will load the user `.profile` file (and changes in the `/etc/profile` file as well). However, that won't help you if the application you start from the menus requires the updated profile to be applied.